# CameraX ImageCapture Hit timeout for jpeg callback

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

I'm trying to implement Image capture as per https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/take-photo, I'm running my device on Temi Robot, the preview seems to work fine but I run into this error and the callback does not get executed when I attempt to capture an image.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pppz.png)

This is the Fragment where the camerax code is called

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(GlobalViewModel.class);
    cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(getContext());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.patrol_fragment, container, false);
}

    @Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    previewView = view.findViewById(R.id.previewView);
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
        try {
            ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
            bindPreview(cameraProvider, view);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "CameraProvider initialization error: " + e.toString());
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(getContext()));
         Just for testing
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                takePicture();
            }
        }, 10000);
}

private void bindPreview(ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider, View view) {
    Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
    CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
            .build();

    preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

    imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
            .setTargetRotation(view.getDisplay().getRotation())
            .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
            .build();

    Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(getActivity(), cameraSelector, imageCapture,
            preview);

    takePicture();

}

private void takePicture() {
    File mediaFile = getMediaFile();

    ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions =
            new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(mediaFile).build();
    imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, viewModel.getExecutorService(),
            new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                    // insert your code here.
                    Log.i(TAG, "Capture success!");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ImageCaptureException error) {
                    // insert your code here.
                    Log.e(TAG, "Capture failed :( " + error.toString());

                }
            }
    );
}

private File getMediaFile() {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "TemiPatrol");
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d(TAG, "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
}

private void sendImageToServer(JSONObject requestJson) {
    // for testing
    viewModel.getExecutorService().execute(() -> {
        JsonPostman postman = new JsonPostman(getActivity());
        postman.postRequest(requestJson);
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You aren't able to take pictures because the `ImageCapture` wasn't set up correctly, you aren't binding it when calling `ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle()`. You should write something like this:

```
Preview preview = ...;
preview.setSurfaceProvider(...);

ImageCapture imageCapture = ...;

// bind both preview and imageCapture
cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture);
```

This will (should) allow calls to `takePicture()` to succeed.

I have 2 other comments about your code.

1. The code that you added for testing purposes (where you schedule an image capture after 10 seconds) should only be executed if the camera setup works. You could run it after the call to `bindToLifecycle()` for example.
2. Binding the use cases to the lifecycle of the fragment's Activity is probably not a good idea. The lifecycleOwner in `bindToLifecycle(LifecycleOwner, ...)` controls when the camera is opened and closed, so you'd typically want to have the camera start when the fragment or its view starts, and have it stop when the fragment or its view stops. Since you're displaying a preview, you can tie the opening/closing of the camera to the lifecycle of the fragment's view, so you can write:

```
cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(getViewLifecycleOwner(), cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture);
```

Comment: I think you missed the part where I binded the ImageCapture as it got cut off by the screen, but the imageCapture was already included in the `bindToLifecycle` method that was called in the `bindPreview` method in `onViewCreated`

I have changed the lifecycle owner as you suggested.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I missed the part where you bind the image capture use case. Are you able to reproduce this issue on other devices? And do you encounter this issue on the Temi Robot running other camera apps, e.g. the camera2 sample app.

Comment: I was initially using the deprecated camera library, the preview and image capture worked fine but there was an issue whereby the images captured were rotated 180 degrees and I couldn't find a way to resolve that issue, so I decided to try camerax. 

I have yet to attempt running the app on other devices / trying the camera2 sample app, but so far the camerax preview works fine.

Comment: Update: I have since tested CameraXBasic and Camera2Basic from https://github.com/android/camera-samples and both since to work on the Temi Robot, both seem to work!